# using find, exec and cp to copy specific files while preserving directory path

Tags: find, cp, exec

I set up the following folders with empty text files:

```
1/a.txt
2/b.txt
```

I want to copy only txt files to another directory while maintaining their directory structure.  So I tried the following commands:

```
mkdir -p temp/s;
find ./ -name '*txt' -exec cp --parents '{}' ./temp/s \;
```

Now I see the following files from my current directory:

```
1/a.txt
2/b.txt
temp/s/1/a.txt
temp/s/2/b.txt
temp/s/temp/s/2/b.txt
```

I don't understand why the final line `temp/s/temp/s/2/b.txt` occurred.  Can someone explain to me why that happened and how I can fix my command such that `temp` is not nested within another `temp` ?

This is the final result that I was expecting:

```
1/a.txt
2/b.txt
temp/s/1/a.txt
temp/s/2/b.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **race condition**: since `temp/s` is in `find`'s search path, `find` is listing files, while the spawned `cp`s are adding new files.

You have to exclude the sub-directory while running `find`:

```
find . -path ./temp/s -prune -o -name '*txt' -exec cp --parents '{}' ./temp/s \;
```

Note that replacing `\;` with `+` will spawn much less `cp` processes.